# Solving an equation involving integral in Matlab

Tags: matlab

How to solve following question in Matlab.
Let α ∈ (−∞,∞).
Then how to solve: 1 + 4 {D<sub>1</sub>(α)−1} / α = 0.4615 in MATLAB?
where D<sub>1</sub>(α) is Debye function defined by:
D<sub>1</sub>(α) = 1/α ∫t/(e<sup>t</sup>−1)dt
(integral from [0 α])

[image: the math]

Comment: Hi, can you please edit your question, put blank lines above and under the code and indent the code by 4 spaces?  That'd make your question readable.

Comment: This isn't code this is latex math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATLAB won't give you an exact answer for this but you could use.

```
syms alpha t real
D = @(alpha)1/alpha * int(t / (exp(t)-1), t, 0, alpha);
solve(1 + 4*(D(alpha) - 1)/alpha == 0.4615, alpha)
```

output is

```
Warning: Cannot solve symbolically. Returning a numeric approximation instead. 
> In solve (line 303) 

ans =

5.0770060488781283390761360077113
```

Edit: After the LaTeX was interpreted and posted I realized I read it wrong. I missed a pair of parenthesis. This issue has been fixed.